# how to send fetch request with ssr nuxt and httpOnly auth

Tags: fetch, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, httponly, asyncdata

I have an SSR nuxt app and laravel backend. In auth, we are using HttpOnly and we are Ok in most of the code but there is a problem in sending requests with fetch and asyncData on the server-side.

I know that only the browser automatically merge a header for auth with request and send it. Now I'm using fetch and this will send requests to the server and there is no browser on the server.

I searched for making custom fetch in nuxt, but I don't find any.
How should I send a request with fetch and asyncdata and do not get a `401 error`?

---

> UPDATE

***: I have to change `nuxt` mode to `spa` from `ssr` unfortunately, because I don't find any answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't found an answer. I changed `axios` part in `nuxt.config.js` like this:

```
axios: {
    baseURL: 'https://api.iranicard.net/api/v1/admin/',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    common: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    retry: { retries: 2 },
    proxyHeaders: false
  },
```

But still after a successful login, when in a component that I used `fetch` or `asyncData`  hook, I got logout and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

fetch won’t send cookies, unless you set the [credentials init option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters). Try setting the `credentials` option to `same-site` or `include` like this:

```
fetch('your-endpoint', { credentials: 'same-site' }).then(...)
```

Comment: Can you tell more about this?
I searched for this, but I don't understand what should I have to do.
Do I have to write code in nuxt? if yes, Where?

Comment: @Esamani77 try setting `axios: { credentials: true }` in your `nuxt.config.js` https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#credentials